# PHP SimpleXML_load_string fails using German characters (umlaute)

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, simplexml

I am experiencing issues parsing a xml string with simplexm_load_string. 
For the heck of it I can't figure out where I went wrong with this script.

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
    <title>ÄÖÜ</title>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you use `simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode($string));`, same result ?

Comment: @Martin: That should have been for analysing only. Now as you know it works, just remove that `ut8_encode` again and save the file in UTF-8 encoding. Then you're really done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the heck of it I can't figure out where I went wrong with this script.

Because you don't save the PHP file as UTF-8 you can not use the string there-in:

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
    <title>ÄÖÜ</title>
</document>
XML;
```

as UTF-8 encoded. Save the file as UTF-8 and it works.

If you'er unsure, you can also do differently:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
    <title>\xC3\x84\xC3\x96\xC3\x9C</title>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
```

That is by specifying the binary bytes from the extended pane in PHP's binary notation so they are immune to different encodings in that part of the octets. This would be pretty robust.

But consider saving your PHP files UTF-8 encoded. That's normally best practice in web-development.

Demo: https://eval.in/private/76c12983305e81

Comment: Thank you both for your help - both ways did work but you pointed me into the right direction - apparently Notepad++ was not configured correctly by me.

Comment: Take care when saving as UTF-8: ***NEVER*** with BOM. Plain UTF-8, no BOM. I know Notepad++ (as any good text-editor) can do both, so *you* need to take care here.

Comment: then all good. just had it the week, those BOMs can become pretty hard to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode($string))
```

Comment: Most likely the file is not Latin-1 but Win-1252 encoded. so this answer while it might be a good guess and seem to work at first, might just turn out wrong. It also does not explain the cause of the issue nor how to fix it already with the file itself.

Comment: @hakre sure, sure, that's true, no doubt, you are right.